# Code outside of Timer?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, timer

I have an extremely simple question. Using CountDownTimer, there is a callback method called `onFinish()`, where one can place code that should execute after the timer is finished.

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Ticking");
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Finished timer"); //Gets called :)
        }
    }.start();

    Log.v(TAG, "Outside of timer code now."); // NEVER GETS CALLED!?
```

However, any code **outside of the timer's `onFinish`** method is not called.

**`Log.v(TAG, "Outside of timer code now.");` never shows.**

---

Is there something I can do to execute code after the timer is finished by simply placing code after `.start()` outside of the anonymous timer instantiation?

P.S. I know I can just use the `onFinish()` method, but why doesn't code outside the timer execute?

Comment: If it's never called - either immediately after `start()` or after the timer finishes, that makes me think that an exception is being thrown, and you're ignoring the stack trace. Is there/are you?

Comment: @AndyTurner Okay, you're right, it is called immediately after `start()`. Does that mean CountDownTimer is asynchronous?

Comment: If the `Outside` message appears before `Finished`, it must be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Log.v(TAG, "Outside of timer code now.");` method executes immediately after you called the `CountDownTimer.start()` method. That is because the "start" method of your "CountDownTimer" class doesn't lock your execution thread, so when you call it then the timer starts and executes asynchronously (a new execution thread is created) and then immediately your "Log.v(TAG, "Outside of timer code now.")" method executes.